# Infinite looping with urllib2 and simplejson

Tags: python, json, urllib2, urllib, simplejson

The following code exhibits strange behaviour when the json response indicates an invalid request. Instead of logging the response and then hitting the "if" block, the code will log the response and immediately jump to the first log call again, and retry the json/urlopen call, etc. This process will repeat indefinitely until I terminate the process. Mind you, when the json response indicates that the url and query were valid and ok, the flow of the program is as you would expect.

```
log.debug('Retreiving json response for %s' % url)
response = simplejson.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
log.debug('Retreived json response: %s' % response)
if response['status'] in ['INVALID_REQUEST', 'REQUEST_DENIED', 'UNKNOWN_ERROR']:
    print 'Problem with request: %s' % response['status']
```

Just to demonstrate the issue, I've included a sample of the generated logs:

```
2012-12-26 09:41:31,505 - json_logger - DEBUG - Retreiving json response for ...
2012-12-26 09:41:31,510 - json_logger - DEBUG - Retreived json response: {'status': 'INVALID_REQUEST', 'results': []}
2012-12-26 09:41:31,512 - json_logger - DEBUG - Retreiving json response for ... 
2012-12-26 09:41:31,530 - json_logger - DEBUG - Retreived json response: {'status': 'INVALID_REQUEST', 'results': []} ...
```

Comment: Th result of the print statement will not be in the log file but will be sent to standard out.  It makes sense that it is not shown in the log file.  Please show the context in which this statements are called.

Comment: It's unlikely that it's jumping to the first log call again; most likely it's just continuing on to the next loop in the code you haven't shown us, which is where the actual problem is.

Comment: You might want to use a `break` statement to break your loop when an error occurs, or a `continue` to continue with the next item.

Comment: Also, as a side note, don't pass a single value to the `%` operator in real code. As documented, it really should be splitting the string into 1-character strings and raising a `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`; the fact that it doesn't is one of the few workarounds for broken code that Guido allowed into his language. Use a 1-element tuple (e.g., `(response,)`).

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to avoid using simplejson's implementation, and just do the following?

```
response = simplejson.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

I'm using loads instead of load, to load a string, and just invoking the read method on the urllib2 object you've created